# APIs automation in Apigee using OpenAPI spec

Tags: openapi, apigee

I have created an apigee API proxy using swagger file, then I modified my swagger file (I added a new endpoint) but this new endpoint doesn't display until in apigee UI until I add it manually (In conditional flows), Is there a rest API provider by Apigee or something allows us to update the endpoints in Apigee dynamically by the edit of the swagger file? and thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which Apigee version you are on but the **Specs** menu on Apigee Edge should allow you to do this. However, this is not available on Apigee-X.

For the management API you would have to create your own script that modifies the endpoints on update.